# AutoHotKey SetTimer immediate 1st iterration

Tags: timer, autohotkey

If i'm using:

```
SetTimer, T1, 5000

T1:
    Send, {1 Down} {1 Up}
return
```

..it runs 1st iterration after 5 seconds.

Is there a way to start 1st iterration immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can just `Gosub`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm)</sup> to the label right before (or after) launching the timer:

```
Gosub, T1
SetTimer, T1, 5000

T1:
    Send, {1 Down} {1 Up}
return
```

Or if you want to ditch the legacy AHK and use a function, you can just call the function first:

```
T1()
SetTimer, T1, 5000

T1()
{
    Send, {1 Down} {1 Up}
}
```

Or even call it inline:
`SetTimer, % ("T1", T1()), 5000`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @0x464e 's answer, you can do the following to run it just once but immediately in a pseudo-thread.

```
SetTimer, T1, -1
```

or

```
SetTimer, T1, -0   ; this works, but I don't recommended it as it's not documented.
```

You can read more about AutoHotkey threading here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm